# How to set Appropriate Text Color which is placed over an image in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android Application. I have a cardView in which there is an image and TextView. I want the color of this textView to be best suited with image

Comment: The solution is check color of image, when you determined the color of image, you need to the text color that has a contrast that matches the color of the image.

You can refer the same question at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42420286/android-how-to-change-text-color-according-to-background-image) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216167/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-my-text-based-on-the-color-of-the-imageview-it-ove)

Answer (score 1):

Image color may not be consistent. So if you want to put a text over it, it is advisable to put the text on a background. Look at the image below and the text at it's left bottom. I put it on a background so it can standout on any image while making sure the background is transparent enough for the image underneath it to show
[image]